Area enclosed by a curve on the Minkowsky model of the hyperbolic 2-space
I'm searching for references on the following topic: consider the Minkowsky 3-space, i.e., the Euclidean sace $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the ''Minkowsky inner product'' $\langle(a,b,c),(x,y,z)\rangle=-ax+by+cz$,. It has a ''norm'' associated, namely $\|u\|=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}$. We induce a Riemannian metric on the 1-sheet hyperboloid
$$\mathbb{H}^2=\{u=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,\|u\|=-1,x>0\}$$
by restricting $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to the tangent spaces of $\mathbb{H}^2$. If $\gamma=\gamma(s)$ is a unitary smooth curve on $\mathbb{H}^2$, we have a Frenet-Serret frame along $\gamma$, given by
$$  \begin{equation}\label{eq:unifiedfrenetframes}
   \begin{cases}
    \gamma'(s)=\vec{t}(s) \\
    \vec{t}'(s)=\gamma(s)+k\vec{e}(s) \\
    \vec{e}'(s) = -k\vec{t}(s)
   \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$
Here, $\vec{e}$ is normal to $\gamma$, $\vec{t}$ is unitary and $k=k(s)$ is the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$ on $\mathbb{H}^2$. Also, the position vector $\gamma(s)$ is in fact normal to the hyperboloid w.r.t. the Minkowsky inner product (such as in the standard sphere with the standard euclidean inner product).
My question is:

Do we have a formula for the area enclosed by a convex (i.e.,
$k(s)>1$) and closed curve $\gamma$ in terms of its parametrization?

Of course we have the same question but not assuming $\gamma$ unitary.
This questions are motivated by another one:
Area inside a curve on the surface of a sphere
Any help would be really appreciated!

Gauss-Bonnet Theorem?
